# Understanding the “self” keyword in python

Tags: python, hashmap, jupyter-notebook

The following source code serves as a “naive” implementation of a HashTable. It is by no means a very good implementation, but it is serving as a demonstration of my concern:
[image]

When tested, this code works for its intended purposes. What I don’t understand is how the **contains** method works. The line, “_ = self[key]” executes without problems if the key is in self.buckets. From my understanding, the line should be, “_ = self.buckets[key]”. Why does self[key] work just as fine? How does self[key] indicate that we are retrieving an item from self.buckets?

Comment: Hello, don't post pictures of code, rather paste the code and format it as such in the ditor.

Comment: `__getitem__` handles dictionary like access on class objects, `self['item'] == self.__getitem__('item')`

Comment: Very important to understand: `self` **is not a keyword**. It is the name conventionally given to the first argument of a method. When a method is called on an instance, the instance is automatically bound to that method and passed as the first argument "magically". But you could call the first parameter `banana` or whatever you want and it wouldn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `self[key]` part is using the `__getitem__` method defined above it, which itself it a wrapper around `self.buckets[...]`. So it is using `self.buckets`, just one step removed.

The syntax `self[key]` is essentially short for `Hashtable.__getitem__(self, key)`, where `self` is your Hashtable instance.